# OpenLdap How to disable/enable/remove user account

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm newbie to OpenLDAP. I have done a bit of research on the above topic and so far couldn't find a satisfactory answer. I would appreciate if anyone can show me how to enable/disable/remove a user account in OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 2):

admin changing user's password is not a good idea. it has several side effects:

- it will cause a login failure.
- it's not easy to re-enable user

I like the solution to add a ACL of userPassword attribute, see the solution here: [acl control userPassword](https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201111/msg00165.html)
 it's clean and effective.

Answer (score 0):

- Disable: using the [password-policy overlay](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.3-Release), set `pwdAccountLockedTime.`
- Enable: clear or remove the above attribute.
- Remove: remove the entry for the user from the DIT.

Comment: I'm using openldap 2.4.31 on Ubuntu and i don't think the ppolicy schema comes with it .. Do i need to add them to slapd.conf? Is there a quick tutorial on setting this up?

Comment: `ppolicy` is not a schema, it is an overlay, and it does indeed come with 2.4.31. You need to read *man slapo-policy.*

Comment: Setting up for this ppolicy is not simple. Is there a simple quick tutorial on this? By the way my OpenLDAP is not using OLC. Can ppolicy works on slapd.conf, the old way?

Comment: Not aware of a tutorial (zytrax.com is the place to look for OpenLDAP), but nothing there on policy Incould see) but it's covered in a book whose title I forget, anyway it's the most obvious OpenLDAP book. OpenLDAP overlays don't care which way you do your configuration.

Comment: The book is Matt Butcher, *Mastering OpenLDAP.*

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for an admin to disable an account is to change the password.

the account could be easily re-activated by giving the user the password and ask the user to change.